# groovy OSX install fails building opencv2 because LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform

Tags: python, ros-groovy, opencv2, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Following the instructions at
http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Source#Building_the_catkin_Workspace

I run

```
./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install
```

But it fails.  greping the logs yeilds

```
Building CXX object modules/python/CMakeFiles/opencv_python.dir/src2/cv2.cpp.o
modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures In file included from /Users/nchalko/ros_catkin_ws/src/opencv2/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp:1:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers/Python.h:55:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers/pyport.h:616:2: error: "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)."
#error "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)."
 ^
```

I played with building opencv by hand but never got only got it to work by not building the python part.

Note:

```
brew install opencv
```

works fine

I am running OS X 10.8.2 (12C60)
And using xcode Version 4.5.2 (4G2008a)

I am stuck.  my pthyon + cmake foo is too weak to know were to start.

So how can I get groovy to install opencv2 on my mac.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51346/groovy-osx-install-fails-building-opencv2-because-long_bit-definition-appears-wrong-for-platform/) by [Nick J Chalko](https://answers.ros.org/users/1591/nick-j-chalko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2013-01-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try using the [OSX install](http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source) instructions ... that might help. Also I don't have this: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers/pyport.h` ... try uninstalling this, since it seems to be causing problems and this isn't where homebrew installs python modules too.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2013-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0